# Accessing Drupal core functions in object-oriented code: Call to undefined function

Tags: 7, rules

I'm a Drupal procedural programmer new to OOP and enjoying it, so some of the techniques are new to me.

I'm getting a fatal error when I'm calling a standard drupal function from within code called within an object that creates a custom Rule. It appears that it's looking for the function drupal_json_encode_helper on the Action object rather than from where it's supposed to look. But why? And how to I tell it to search within Drupal-land rather than object-land?

I'm on D7 with xautoload and composer, modifying the [fluxdropbox](https://drupal.org/project/fluxdropbox) module that uses [fluxservices](https://drupal.org/project/fluxservice) to use PSR-0 for external libraries.

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   Drupal\fluxdropbox\Plugin\Rules\Action\drupal_json_encode_helper()"

Here's the code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains MakeNodes.
 */

namespace Drupal\fluxdropbox\Plugin\Rules\Action;

use Drupal\fluxdropbox\Plugin\Service\DropboxAccountInterface;
use Drupal\fluxdropbox\Rules\RulesPluginHandlerBase;

/**
 * Action for posting a status message on a page.
 */
class MakeNodes extends RulesPluginHandlerBase implements \RulesActionHandlerInterface {

  /**
   * Defines the action.
   */
  public static function getInfo() {
    return static::getInfoDefaults() + array(
      'name' => 'fluxdropbox_make_nodes',
      'label' => t('Make Nodes from Text Fiels'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'account' => static::getAccountParameterInfo(),
      ),
    );
  }

  /**
   * Executes the action.
   */
  public function execute(DropboxAccountInterface $account) {
            //here I build a nice array
            file_put_contents(drupal_json_encode_helper($feed_array), $path . '/novel.txt');

  }
}
```

Comment: Is this for D7 or D8? Any reason not to use the standard Rules hooks? e.g `hook_rules_action_info` etc..

Comment: It's D7 code that uses xautoload. I'm copying another module's code. Everything works and it would be a pain to re-write it, I'm just hitting this one error related to autoloading.

Comment: Just saying, xautoload (and autoload in general) does not help you with procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because [`drupal_json_encode()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!json-encode.inc/function/drupal_json_encode_helper/7) is defined in [includes/json-encode.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!json-encode.inc/7), which is not a file that is normally included when Drupal boots. To use that function, you should use code similar to the one [`drupal_json_encode()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7) uses, although you really should use `drupal_json_encode()`.

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/json-encode.inc';
file_put_contents(drupal_json_encode_helper($feed_array), $path . '/novel.txt');
```

The code I would use is the following one.

```
file_put_contents(drupal_json_encode($feed_array), $path . '/novel.txt');
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. Figured this out, actually. The objective-ness of the error had me confused.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you change your code from

```
file_put_contents(drupal_json_encode_helper($feed_array), $path . '/novel.txt');
```

to

```
file_put_contents(drupal_json_encode($feed_array), $path . '/novel.txt');
```

The correct file will be included for json encoding.